# Redirect *.php to path using web.config file

Tags: redirect, rewrite-rules, iis

I want to redirect

```
blog/customfilename.php
```

to

```
blog/customfilename
```

using `web.config`file.

I applied this rule:

```
<rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*).php" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="is-quickbooksonline-down" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="is-quickbooksonline-down" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="is-quickbooksonline-down.php" />
</rule>
```

but this rule applies on all routes inside blog.

I already applied all tags like in comment section. Trying

```
<match url = "is-quickbooksonline-down.php" />
```

or example does not output the desired result.

Comment: <rule name="hide .php extension" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*).php" />
      <conditions>
      <add input="is-quickbooksonline-down" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="is-quickbooksonline-down" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="is-quickbooksonline-down.php" />
  </rule>

Comment: <match url = "is-quickbooksonline-down.php" /> or something etc no fruitful result